# Is it actually possible to transplant melanocytes inside the hair follicle or the surrounding skin?

Tags: melanin, vitiligo, hair-color, hair-transplant, melanocytes

I saw this experiment ([link](https://file.scirp.org/pdf/JCDSA_2013012815274133.pdf)) about the treatment of gray hair in vitiligo patients by direct melanocytes transplant and it looks like they actually managed to transplant melanocytes into gray hairs and restore the color to them. In another article([link](http://www.odermatol.com/odermatology/20162/11.Follicular-SharquieK.pdf)) by the same doctors they stated:

> In cases of gray hairs, the grafted melanocytes will move from regimented epidermis into the outer root sheath then move down to reach the hair matrix thus inducing pigmented hair.

Is it actually possible to transplant melanocytes inside the hair follicle or the surrounding skin?

Comment: Since you are collecting various formulas, scroll down. :  http://www.chineseherbshealing.com/jujube-fruit-da-zao/

Comment: Ask yourself why someone who knows how to prevent gray hair or turn gray hair back to its natural color isn't a billionaire and I think you'll find the answer.